# ReactJS - How to get form value from multiple child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, post, components

I know this might have some similar questions but I don't seem to able to find the solution for my situation.

I have a form that will be submitted with the content of the child component, the child component is appended onClick and can be appended infinitely. How can I get the value from all the child component, and to post it.

This is index.js

```
class ListOfProducts extends React.Component {
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.appendChild = this.appendChild.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      children: [],
      }
  }  

    appendChild() {
      this.setState({
        children: [
          ...this.state.children, <NewComponent/>
        ]
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form>
          <div>
            <pre><h2 className="h2"> Sales Order</h2></pre>
            <div className="box" style={{height: '520px', width: '1300px', position: 'relative', overflow: 'auto', padding: '0'}}>
            <div style={{height: '1000px', width: '1000px', padding: '10px'}}>

              <div>
                    {this.state.children.map(child => child )}
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

          <button className="addbut" onClick={() => this.appendChild()}>Add Items</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    )  
  }
}
```

This is partial code of NewComponent.JS

```
            <select
              name="sel"
              className="sel"
              value={this.state.selecteditems}
              onChange={(e) => 
                this.setState({selecteditems: e.target.value})}
            >
            {this.state.data.map(item => 
              <option key={item.productID} value={item.unitPrice}>
                {item.itemName}
              </option>
            )}
            </select>

            {/*unit price*/}
            <p>Unit Price: RM {this.state.selecteditems} </p>

            {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
              <p>Quantity: </p>
            ) : null }

            {/*button to add quantity*/}
            {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
              <button onClick={this.addPro}> + </button>
            ) : null }

            {/*textbox for quantity*/}
            {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
              <input type="text" ref="quan" placeholder="Quantity" 
                value={this.state.quantity}
                onChange={(e) => 
                  this.setState({quantity: e.target.value})}
                >
                </input>
            ) : null }

            {/*button to decrease quantity}*/}
            {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
              <button onClick={this.decPro}> - </button>
            ) : null }

            {/*subtotal*/}
            {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
              <p>Sub Total: RM {this.state.subtot} </p>
            ) : null }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of getting the value from the child component -

1. Have a state management system (something like redux) which can actually store the data of all the child components. As and when the child component's data changes, it should be synced to the store and the same can be used by the parent to post the data on submit.
2. Assign `ref` to each of the child component when it gets appended. save those ref values in a array. Iterate through those references on submit of the form and call some specific getter function of child component to give you its data.

Preferred way is the first method.

Comment: With the way I am appending the child, how should I add ref to each of the component?

Comment: I was thinking of assigning string values to ref, like "childComponent1" etc but that is not the preferred way of assigning refs as per the new react versions.

Comment: Is there any other alternatives than redux? I heard it is quite complicated

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dumb: add callback like this

`<NewComponent onChange={this.onNewComponentChange}/>`

(and implement calling of this `onChange` callback at every change at NewComponent of course)

Comment: How do I call the onChange callback at the NewComponent?

Comment: `this.props.onChange()`

Comment: This is to retrieve the value right, how can I like store them?

Comment: You can store it at some array at state of `ListOfProducts` as you do not like Redux (i.e. setState).